# gridview control capable of displaying rich text in WinForms

Tags: winforms, controls, grid

I'm looking for a WinForms control that would allow me to display data in a table like manner but with some rich content such as different font colors, images. I do not need data-binding etc., just a "table of RichTextBox controls". I suppose it wouldn't be difficult to build such a control myself, but I thought I'd ask first...

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have the option of creating your own DataGridView column type. I've done this a few times recently and found that it works quite well. It takes surprisingly little code and knowledge of GDI to put together something very nice.

What information are you trying to display in your grid?